# docker dynamodb -sharedDb option

Tags: docker, amazon-dynamodb

I'm trying to start dynamodb on localhost via, using official [repo](https://hub.docker.com/r/amazon/dynamodb-local)

I tried the following

```
docker run -p 8000:8000 amazon/dynamodb-local -sharedDb
docker run -p 8000:8000 amazon/dynamodb-local --sharedDb
docker run -p 8000:8000 amazon/dynamodb-local --sharedDb --dbPath=/usr/local/var/dynamodb
docker run -p 8000:8000 amazon/dynamodb-local -sharedDb -dbPath=/usr/local/var/dynamodb
docker run -p 8000:8000 amazon/dynamodb-local -sharedDb -dbPath /usr/local/var/dynamodb
```

and I just get the following message

```
Unrecognized option: -sharedDb
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
```

or

```
Unrecognized option: -dbPath
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
```

How do I pass options to dynamodb?
I took those from [official docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DynamoDBLocal.UsageNotes.html)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [Compose samples in the AWS docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DynamoDBLocal.DownloadingAndRunning.html#docker) look like the image is configured with `ENTRYPOINT ["java"]`, so you have to start the options (the command string) with `-jar DynamoDBLocal.jar` to tell the JVM what to run.

```sh
docker run -p 8000:8000 amazon/dynamodb-local \
  -jar DynamoDBLocal.jar -sharedDb
```

Comment: for `-sharedDb` option is ok, successful. And how do I use it for `-dbPath` ?
it gives me the error `Invalid directory for database creation.`

Comment: did you ever figure this out? getting the same error and google isn't returning anything useful

Comment: @stevenhurwitt nope I haven't. Maybe you should open own stackoverflow question to solve it, I no longer use dynamodb