# Table created successfully but dynamoDB cannot find it boto3

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-dynamodb, localhost, boto3

I created a script in python thats setup a table in a dynamoDB.
The dynamoDB instance is running locally in a docker container.
When I'm debugging the script everything seems to work fine: The configuration is correct, the table status is `ACTIVE`, the responses from the `table.put_item` actions are `200 OK`, there are **no** exceptions...
Yet if I try to run via the command-line the command: `aws dynamodb list-tables --endpoint-url http://localhost:8000 --region localhost` I get:

```json
{
    "TableNames": []
}
```

Any ideas why it's happening?

here is my code:

```py
import boto3
from mocksForDynamo import mocks
from botocore.config import Config

ENDPOINT_DYNAMO = 'http://localhost:8000'
TABLE_NAME = 'my_table'

def dynamo_setup():
     config = Config(
        region_name = 'localhost',
        signature_version = 'v4',
        retries = {
            'max_attempts': 10,
            'mode': 'standard'
        }
    )
    dynamo = boto3.resource('dynamodb', endpoint_url=ENDPOINT_DYNAMO, config=config)

    table = dynamo.create_table(
        TableName=TABLE_NAME,
        KeySchema=[{ "AttributeName": 'id', "KeyType": 'HASH' }],
        AttributeDefinitions=[{ "AttributeName": 'id', "AttributeType": 'S' }],
        ProvisionedThroughput={
            "ReadCapacityUnits": 10,
            "WriteCapacityUnits": 10
        }
    )

    table.wait_until_exists()

    for mock in mocks:
        response = table.put_item(Item=mock)
        print('item created: ', response)

def main():
    dynamo_setup()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Thanks!

I'm trying to access a table that was created using the boto3 api on a local dynamoDB instance.

Comment: I have never tried to run dynamoDB locally, however, in AWS documentation (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DynamoDBLocal.DownloadingAndRunning.html) and (https://hub.docker.com/r/amazon/dynamodb-local) I don't see the use of the --region parameter, just the endpoint url, is it possible it's messing with your cli code?

Comment: Hi @PandaBlue, I tried both with and without the `--region` flag, and there wasn't any difference.
Yet when I checked with chatGPT one of the options that where suggested is that probably the region isn't configured correctly, because the default region of AWS is `us-east-1`.

Comment: I tried your code locally, (removing the mocks part by feeding an array `[{"id":"hello"},{"id":"world"}]`, I then ran the commands: `docker pull amazon/dynamodb-local` and `docker run -p 8000:8000 amazon/dynamodb-local`, in another terminal, I ran you python code, then ran the command: `aws dynamodb list-tables --endpoint-url http://localhost:8000 --region localhost` and see the table "my_table" in the list.

Comment: I tried to reproduce this according to your steps, still not working :(  
The `tableNames` property is an empty array.
@PandaBlue

Comment: You didn't change any of the configuration? 
Do you think there is a problem on my local machine?
I really in doubt because python and docker should be cross-platform...

Comment: I kept all standard, I tried on an EC2 (amazon linux ami - rhel fedora) connected using a vscode extension, (which manages all forwarded ports, maybe check this). nb: As it is in memory for the dyanmodb docker it has a tendency to loose the info if kept idle

Comment: It has a dendency to loose info? can you elaborate? btw I'm using a windows machine @PandaBlue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because of how DynamoDB Local sets a directory for every access key credential you use. The easiest way to overcome this is to use the `sharedDB` option which gives you a single database no matter the credentials you use.

> If you use the -sharedDb option, DynamoDB creates a single database file named shared-local-instance.db. Every program that connects to DynamoDB accesses this file. If you delete the file, you lose any data that you have stored in it.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DynamoDBLocal.UsageNotes.html

`docker run -p 8000:8000 amazon/dynamodb-local -jar DynamoDBLocal.jar -sharedDb`

Comment: How can I enable this option for the docker container? This article seems more relevant to the java application than the docker image

Comment: In your `docker-compose.yml` as described here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DynamoDBLocal.DownloadingAndRunning.html

Comment: found the relevant post for docker container: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65990761/docker-dynamodb-shareddb-option

Comment: you can do it with running `docker run -p 8000:8000 amazon/dynamodb-local -jar DynamoDBLocal.jar -sharedDb`, no need for `docker-compose.yml`